# How do you prove a limit with epsilon delta when the X is negative?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Use epsilon-delta definition of the limit to show that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $(-5x+6)=6$.

I have done these before, but I get confused because of the $-5x$. This is probably more of a weakness in my algebra than calculus.

$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)-L| &< \varepsilon, \\
|-5x+6-6| &< \varepsilon, \\
|-5x| &< \varepsilon, \\
-\varepsilon < -5x &< \varepsilon, \\
\end{align*}$$

When I remove the $-5$, what happens with the greater than and less than signs?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You can divide each expression by $-5$ and flip the direction of both inequalities to get $e/5 > x > -e/5$. Alternatively you could start from $|-5x| < e$ and notice that $|-5x|=5|x|$.

Comment: And that would make delta e/5? Because delta > 0?

Comment: Yes, if $|x| < \epsilon / 5 =: \delta$ then your work shows that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, please typeset your mathematics using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), to improve readability.